# load data into table in Mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I created 4 columns for a table

```
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE videoinfo (
    id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT, 
    date DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    src_ip CHAR(32), 
    hash CHAR(150));
""")
```

I have a .txt file which has three columns of data inside. I want to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`command to insert data, but the problem is ,the table I created now has four columns, the first one is the id, so, can mysql automatically insert data from the second column or extra command is needed?

Many thanks!

Comment: When dealing with an error, always state what the error is.

Comment: Don't make edits that invalidate others' answers, unless you made a mistake in the question that doesn't exist in the actual problem. Did you leave out the underscore in `AUTO_INCREMENT` in your original code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AUTO INCREMENT` isn't valid syntax. If you check MySQL's documentation for the [`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) statement, you'll see the proper keyword is `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Additionally, `date` is a keyword, so you'll need to quote it with backticks, as mentioned on the [MySQL identifier](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html) documentation page. The documentation also lists all [keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html), which must be quoted to use them as identifiers. To be safe, you could simply quote all identifiers.

To insert data only into some columns, you can explicitly specify columns. For [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_name'
    INTO TABLE videoinfo
    (`date`, src_ip, hash)
```

For the [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) statement:

```
INSERT INTO videoinfo (`date`, src_ip, hash)
  VALUES (...);
```

This, too, is revealed in the MySQL manual. Notice a pattern?

Comment: but the data is in txt file, I need to use LOAD DATA command instead of insert into

Comment: @manxing: you should show a sample of the data you're working with and give an SQL [code sample](http://sscce.org/) showing how you're loading the data.